# Video View in View Pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-videoview

I have a viewpager with different fragments, all of these has a same  videoview in it. If I switch to the last page it shows black screen but  video time is moving forward remaining pages video is running well only last  create problem. any solution?